# Calculate the limit $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$$

I believe the limit equals $1$, and I think I can prove it with the squeeze theorem, but I don't really know how.

Any help is appreciated, I'd like to receive some hints if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Write it as a Riemann sum.

Comment: This was asked before.

Comment: @mickep No thanks.

Comment: @Did can you copy a link here? Couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\left({1\over \sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124342/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-left1-over-sqrtn211-over-sqrtn22)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For every $n>0$,
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Can you continue with Squeeze theorem?

Comment: Got it. Great, thanks. I'll post the answer in full, later, as well for future users.

Comment: Can you maybe explain why the expression in the middle is smaller and bigger than the left and right expressions?

Comment: Because n->inf, we must have a N>0 s.t. n>N. Observe the expression in the middle, it is obvious that the maximum term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ with the condition n>N , if we replace all the term with the maximum term, it is obviously greater than the middle expression.The left expression follow the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write the term of interest as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k/n^2}}$$

To evaluate the limit we can expand the summand using the binomial theorem as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k/n^2}}=1-\frac{k}{2n^2} +O(k^2/n^4)$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+O(k/n^2)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\left(n+O(1)\right)\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand the method 2, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, in Riemann sums, the function one considers the integral of, should not depend on $n$. A cute exercise would be to find examples where $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf_n\left(\frac{k}n\right)\ne\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @Did While the approach will generally not be tractable, the development is valid in this example, is it not?  I am happy to delete if you think it might mislead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final answer I got, thanks to all the help:

For every $n>0$,$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right) \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$

Using the squeeze theorem, we calculate the middle expression's limit.

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}=\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}= \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{ {n^2}}{{n^2+n}}}=\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{ \frac{n^2}{n^2}}{{\frac{n^2}{n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2}}}}=\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=1$ from limits arithmetic.

Likewise, we can calculate the right hand side and reach to the conclusion that the original sequence approaches $1$.