# Examing a limit of sum of square roots

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Calculate the following limit:
>   $$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right)$$

I think this limit equals $1$. I am not sure. Tried using the squeeze theorem:

$$1 \leq  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right) \leq n\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$.

It's quite clear why the right hand side is bigger than the middle term, but is $1$ really smaller of equals to the middle term?

Please note I can't use integrals here nor taylor series.

Thanks!

Comment: Your left inequality is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, can you please explain why?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is right ?

Comment: Since the denominator in the right hand side is smaller than all the denominators in the middle term, and I multiply it $n$ times in the value of the nominator of the middle term $1$.

Comment: Sorry, this explanation is undecipherable. As far as I know, $1\le1/{\sqrt {10}}+1/{\sqrt {11}}+1/{\sqrt {12}}$ is false, for instance.

Comment: Surely for $n=1$ the middle term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, which is less than 1?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think I understand which inequality is wrong - the lower or higher bound?

Comment: I said left and shown an example. Isn't that enough ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry! I thought you mean "right inequality"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\left({1\over \sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124342/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-left1-over-sqrtn211-over-sqrtn22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1\le k\le n$,$$\frac1{(n+1)^2}<\frac1{n^2+k}<\frac1{n^2}$$

then

$$\frac n{n+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}<\frac nn.$$

Comment: Thanks four all your help!