# Proving the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I think I tried everything I know when trying to prove this limit 
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)=1$$
but I think that either there is some rule that I don't know or I am simply missing the creativity needed to solve it.. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Too many parentheses there...in fact, only the first and last big ones are required.

Comment: I know but It is only because I use symolab to generate the MathJax code for the expression that I need since I'm relatively new to this website and still haven't had much time to study the language used. :/

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/580372/269624) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/959824/269624)

Comment: why not using euler maclaurin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\left({1\over \sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over \sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124342/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-left1-over-sqrtn211-over-sqrtn22)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: squeeze that thing

$$\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Comment: Oh my god I have tried the squeeze theorem so many times and this never occurred to me. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @intersomnium We all get into long loops trying to prove stuff some times. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Very informally,

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac1n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac2{n^2}}}+\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac n{n^2}}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\frac xn}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the following "creative"...

It's easy to see that $a_n:=-2\sqrt{n} +\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}}$ is decreasing, and since $$2\sqrt{n}-2=\int_1^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}}$$ we find $a_n$ converges. It thus suffices to note your expression can be written as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2+n} \frac1{\sqrt{k}} -\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac1{\sqrt{k}}=2\sqrt{n^2+n}-2n+o(1)=2n\left(\sqrt{1+1/n}-1\right)+o(1)\to1.$$